# It doesn't work when add rootController and mainView for my window

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've some problem when add view and controller on self.window.
Here is the code.
My BookListViewController class owns a view object named BookListView.
The problem occurs at `makeKeyAndVisible` methods.
Thanks.

```
self.bookListViewController = [[bookListViewController alloc] init];
CGRect applicationRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.bookListViewController.bookListView = [[[BookListView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationBound] autorelease];
self.window.rootController = self.bookListViewController;
[self.window addSubview:self.bookListViewController.bookListView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: what do you mean " The problem occurs at makeKeyAndVisible methods."? Are these codes in "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
" method?

Comment: yes. In runtime it did run into this didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and crash on makeKeyAndVisible

Comment: I found my mistake, I've misused the view class. Thx~